# css/html necessary to create forum style message

Tags: html, css

can anyone tell me any guides/hints for the css/html necessary to create a layout similar to the 
message part of a forum:

```
------------------------
[8] User1
    Some msg
------------------------

[8] User2
    Another message
------------------------
```

Is this 1 main div and several child divs or something simpler like a css styled listitems or table, etc?
Please let me know the "correct" way to achieve this layout without newest css3/html5/beta code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An Example:

```
<style>
    .message {margin-bottom: 15px; }
    .image {float:left; margin-right: 10px; }
    .user {float:left; font-weight:bold; color:#009; margin-bottom: 5px; }
    .content { margin-left: 30px;font-style:italic; color:#; }
</style>
<div>
    <div class="message">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/df125f7b89730a39163bb17c1c18c1d9?s=18&d=identicon&r=PG" /></div>
        <div class="user">Silvertiger</div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <div class="content">Does this work as expected?</div>
    </div>
    <div class="message">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/98d247dcb9453a0d5adc70cd6b3acde9?s=18&d=identicon&r=PG" /></div>
        <div class="user">user2309722</div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <div class="content">Indeed sir it appears to, Thank you</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Your example was perfect - just enough to learn and play around with

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```
<div id="thread">
  <div class="thread-post">
    Post #1 contents
  </div>
  <div class="thread-post">
    Post #2 contents
  </div>
  <div class="thread-post">
    Post #3 contents
  </div>
</div>
```

And for CSS, you would do something like:

```
.thread-post {
  padding: 10px
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd
}
.thread-post:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eee /* For distinguishing every other post */
}
```

Modify as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with one div for each couple author info + message, then, inside of each it would be some kind of floating left div for the box containing author info (username, avatar, etc) (as it is usually seen on forums but the style is up to you) along with another div to contain the linked message.

Comment: Yeay I tried my best with what I was given. I just wrote a quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this **:**  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/arshadabbas/AWrtd/2/)

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="list">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
    <div class="list">BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</div>
    <div class="list">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</div>
    <div class="list">DDDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
</div>
```

With css as **:**

```
.box {
position: absolute;
border: 2px solid grey;
}

.list {
line-height: 30px;
}

.list:not(:last-child) {
border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```